# Ruby Pig Latin Multiple Arguments

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm trying to write code for to convert strings to pig latin

```
def translate(str) 
   alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a
   vowels = %w[a e i o u]
   consonants = alpha - vowels

  if vowels.include?(str[0])
     str + 'ay'
  elsif str[0..1] == 'qu'
     str[2..-1]+'quay' 
  elsif consonants.include?(str[0]) && str[1..2]=='qu'
     str[3..-1]+str[0..2]+'ay' 
  elsif consonants.include?(str[0]) &&    consonants.include?(str[1]) && consonants.include?(str[2])
  str[3..-1] + str[0..2] + 'ay'
 elsif consonants.include?(str[0]) && consonants.include?(str[1])
   str[2..-1] + str[0..1] + 'ay'
elsif consonants.include?(str[0])
   str[1..-1] + str[0] + 'ay'
 elsif str[0..1] == 'qu'
 str[2..-1]+'quay'
else

  return str
  end
 end
```

This code works perfect for converting one word strings, for example: translate("monkey").
What i'm trying to do is make it possible for this code to accept multiple words as well (within the same string)...following the above criteria for converting into pig latin, example: 
translate("please help") => "easeplay elphay"

thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to translate a single word why not just split up the task into two methods:

```
def translate(str)
  str.split.map { |word| translate_word(word) }.join
end

def translate_word(str)
  # Your old translate code here
end
```

Comment: awesome thanks...haven't reviewed that in my review course yet....i'll look into it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

What I would do for this is:

use the #split method to make your str variable into an array of words (or 1 word if its only 1 word).

afterwards you can use the array#each method to iterate through each array index.
i.e.

```
str = "hello"
str = str.split(" ") # str now equals ["hello"]
```

for multiple variables:

```
str = "hello world"
str- str.split(" ") #now equals ["hello", "world"]
```

then you can use the .each method:

```
str.each do |<variable name you want to use>| 
   <how you want to manipulate the array>
   end
```

for the pig latin program you could do:

```
str.each do|element| 
  if vowels.include?(element)
    <do whatever you want here>
  elsif
    <do whatever>
  else 
    <do whatver>
  end
end
```

this will iterate through each element in the array and translate it (if there is only one element it will still work)